# Integration With Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I've never used the FaceBook SDK before so I'm not sure what I should be using or whether what I'm thinking of can actually be done. But I want to try to integrate some Facebook functionality with my ASP.NET MVC3 application.

**What I need to do:**

I want to be able to access someone's Facebook account (granted their permission) and allow them to send out invitations to my website. But, when a friend clicks on the link in the invitation message (whether a wall post, PM... whatever), follows through and registers on the site, I want to be able to track that (maybe by appending the ID or username of the this user to the invitation link, and then extract it from the query string when the invited person/friend registers).

**Questions:**

1. From what I've read so far and according to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee376924), what I think I should be using is the Facebook Connect API. Am I right?
2. Is what I'm trying to achieve actually doable? Basically, can I append the username to the invitation link? Is Facebook okey with that?
3. Do you have any good resources other than the Facebook Developer Wiki? Share them please!

P.S: I do not want users to login to my website using their Facebook account. I have my own Membership system. I just want to allow them to invite their friends to register at my website and track that. More requirements might arise but for now that is all what I need.

Your help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Ok I went ahead and created some test app using the Developer FB app to do some experiments. One thing I do not understand though...

**Canvas Page:** The base URL of your app on Facebook.

**Canvas URL:** Facebook pulls the content for your app's canvas pages from this base URL.

So what exactly is the Canvas URL? From what I understand, it's a URL to a resource (page?) on my website which Facebook can display inside the Canvas Page, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. yes
2. Yes
3. Facebook documentation + facebook developers forum, that should be all for you. Also, as you are using asp.net mvc, [facebooksdk discussion](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) will help you also if you use that library. I will stringly recommend to use that library.

Also, it seems, you are a beginner on facebook api with c#. If so, you can consider my blog post for beginners on [facebook open graph api tutorial in c#](http://codesamplez.com/development/facebook-graph-api-c-sharp). There also some other related posts also.Hope you may like them.

Let me know if you wanted to know something else also specifically.

Comment: Hi Rana! That was definitely helpful! + 1 for that! And yes you are right, I'm a total beginner with the Facebook API, I never touched it before. What I'm trying to do should be very straight forward (I assume) I simply want to do the following: invite a friend, he clicks accept, he gets redirected to my registration page. And that's it (at least for now). Could you provide a code example that highlights how this could be done please? Thanks again!

Comment: I went through your blog and read most of the posts. I also read some of the documentation again and I do not think the Open Graph API is what I need. I need to consume the Facebook For Websites API. I also have to create a Facebook app and authenticate users from my site to access their friends' data. But if I'm going to create a Facebook app that simply redirects to my registration page, what should be there in the app itself?! This is really confusing me... I do not want an app like a game or anything like that, I just want to redirect to my site and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Nope.  The Developer Wiki has its issues but the Facebook Docs usually solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've been reading the Facebook Docs today and I think I figured out a way of doing this but I'm still not sure about certain stuff. I know that by sending Requests I could fill in the optional `data` JSON attribute and here's where I can add the inviter's username. But I'm trying to stay away from having to create a Facebook app for that, any suggestions on that?

Comment: Nope.  You need to create a FB app to access anything other than basic information.  Its not a big deal to do it, just a signup screen.

Comment: hmmm... In that case, what I really need the application to do (at least for now) is simply redirect that user to my registration page... I'll play around with the Developer app and see what I could do with that...